# Let $X$ a random vector with joint probability distribution $f(x, y)=k(x+y) I_{(0,1)}(x) I_{(0,1)}(y)$ find k

Tags: probability

Let $X$ a random vector with joint probability distribution $f(x, y)=k(x+y) I_{(0,1)}(x) I_{(0,1)}(y)$

find $k$
Im a little confused because i know that $I_{(0,1)}(x) $ and $I_{(0,1)}(y) $  are a Indicator functions but i dont know what exactly means in $f(x,y)$

is that $x\in (0,1)$?

so what I do is  calculate

\begin{equation}
\int _{0}^{1} \int _{0}^{1} k(x+y) \cdot dx \cdot dy=k
\end{equation}
and then $k=1$ is right?

Comment: It means the following: If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, $f(x,y)$ is the *product* of the *numbers* $k$, $x+y$, $I_{(0,1)}(x)$ (which is the number $1$ if $x \in (0,1)$, and is $0$ otherwise) and $I_{(0,1)}(y)$ (which is $1$ if $y \in (0,1)$, and $0$ otherwise).

Comment: @azif00 $k(x+y)=1$ if $x\in (0,1)$?

Comment: What about $y$?

Comment: @azif00 $k(x+y)=1$ if $x\ in (0,1) $ and $k(x+y)=1$ if $y \in (0,1)$ ? but what if $x=1/2$ and $y=2$?

Comment: If $y = 2$, probability density is $0$. What you have done to find $k$ is correct.